# Should previously misclassified data be have a higher 'Sample Weight' than normally sourced training data when performing incremental learning?

Tags: classification, python, svm, scikit-learn

I am currently developing a classifier with online/incremental learning. I am using scikit to create the model and run `partial_fit` after an initial **training** of the model. If their is a new class, or there is no model already, I run:

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="l1", average=True)
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

and if there is only new data on classes that have already been initially trained, I run:

```
clf = joblib.load(output_file)  # load already trained model
clf.partial_fit(X, Y)
```

For both of these methods of training I then run:

```
joblib.dump(clf, output_file) # save model
```

---

I currently am receiving manual feedback on a classification when **predicting**:

```
clf = joblib.load(output_file) # load model
clf.predict(X1)
```

I want the model to learn from its mistakes by retraining the model with the `X1` data when it got the prediction wrong. Is it sufficient to just rerun `clf.partial_fit(X1, Y)` with the manual classification or would it be better to perhaps give it a heavier `sample weight` so it **really** makes sure it doesn't make that mistake again? Although all `X` **training** data in the first place will be manually classified and 100% accurate.

---

## Edit

Moderators please may you at least explain what you do not understand?

Comment: What is unclear? do I give a higher sample weight to data that was previously misclassified when retraining a model? Simples :)

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but it appears to be only about code, which is generally off topic here. This may be an on topic machine learning question, but it is asked only in Scikit-learn code, that I don't read. Perhaps you could rewrite your question in a software-neutral way that makes the question easier to understand by people who don't use Python, & make clear that you aren't asking for code help.